# duplicity: UnsupportedBackendScheme: scheme not supported in url: dpbx:///

Tags: dropbox, duplicity, debian-stretch

I'm trying to use `duplicity` to backup a directory to `DropBox` in `Debian Stretch`. However, `duplicity` gives me the error:

```
UnsupportedBackendScheme: scheme not supported in url: dpbx:///
```

I have verified that `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/backends/dpbxbackend.py` and `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/backends/dpbxbackend.pyc` exist so I don't know what the problem is. Could anybody please guide me?

The command I run is:

```
duplicity full ~/alfresco/ dpbx:///
```

Answer (score 0):

I was running the same issue using duplicity 0.7.18.2 in Ubuntu 16.04 and I solved it by reinstalling python-openssl:

1. sudo apt purge python-openssl
2. pip install pyopenssl

Answer (score 0):

make sure to have the `dropbox` python library installed, It seems that duplicity is just trying to import the backend plugin, and it is failing with `ImportError: dropbox` or something, and that results in the `UnsupportedBackendScheme` error

this should work:

```
pip2.7 install dropbox
```